# What is the integral of $e^{-\alpha|t|}e^{ivt}e^{-ipt}$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Given $\alpha, v > 0$, I'm supposed to get to the following result:
$$
g(p) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha|t|}e^{ivt}e^{-ipt}dt =\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^{2}+(v-p)^{2}}
$$

I've tried calculating it as:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{((v-p)i+\alpha)t}dt\ +\ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{((v-p)i-\alpha)t}dt
$$

but I got stuck at

$$
\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^{2}+(v-p)^{2}}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\alpha(e^{(v-p)ix}-e^{-(v-p)ix})}{e^{\alpha x}(\alpha^{2}+(v-p)^{2})}
$$

---

I also tried calculating the integral as

$$
i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin((v-p)t)e^{\alpha|t|}dt+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos((v-p)t)e^{\alpha|t|}dt
$$

but that didn't lead me very far.

---

This is an exercise I have to solve in the context of a (relatively easy) first semester math course in a Computer Science bachelor's.

Comment: Why did you stop there, if you evaluate the limit it goes to $0$ due to the $e^{\alpha x}$ term in the denominator.

Comment: Oh god, I missed the $i$ in the exponents in the numerators. That means the numerator is bounded, right?

Comment: Yes, actually what you have in the numerator is a variation of the exponential form of the $\sin$ which has an absolute value of $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that: $$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{((v-p)i+\alpha)t} dt = \lim_{b \to -\infty} \int_{b}^{0} e^{((v-p)i +\alpha)t} dt = \lim_{b \to -\infty} \frac{1}{((v-p)i +\alpha)}[1-e^{((v-p)i +\alpha) b}]  = \frac{1}{((v-p)i +\alpha)}$$

Can you similarly see the next integral as well?

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. I was getting hung up on the last step. More precisely, I didn't see that $\lim_{b\to\infty}e^{((v-p)i+\alpha)b} = 0$.

Comment: Oh yeah, small typo on my part there. I don't imagine anyone else will answer and your answer really did help, so I'll gladly give it a green tick.